# Running A2ensite and Apache Reload with cron

Tags: php, apache, cron

What I'd like to do is call a2ensite and service apache2 reload from a shell_exec when a user registers their domain on my server. I've tried setting it up with cron jobs, to no avail

```
*/5 * * * * /etc/apache2/sites-available/a2ensite *
```

And then inside the a2ensite file I have

```
#!bin/bash
#Enables Sites every five minutes.
a2ensite *
```

And then for apache reload I have

```
*/30 * * * * service apache2 reload
```

I have these two edited with sudo crontab -e and had no errors when I put them in, but I just waited an hour after registering and my example.com.conf file is there now. Inside my root html I have my example.com folder, but sites enabled does not have it and I have no idea if apache reloaded. If anyone can just point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated
I also tried during the user registration

```
shell_exec("sudo /etc/apache2/sites-available/a2ensite");
```

And ran visudo and added

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/apache2/sites-available/a2ensite
```

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I did not unfortunately.